# Convert named types to unnamed types

Tags: go, struct

Say I have a struct of UnnamedTypes:

```
type UnnamedTypes struct {
    i []int
    f []float64
}
```

And some named types in a struct:

```
type I []int
type F []float64

type NamedTypes struct {
    i I
    f F
}
```

What's the easiest way to assign NamedTypes struct to an UnnamedTypes struct?

```
func main() {
    var u UnnamedTypes
    var n NamedTypes

    u.i = []int{1,2}
    u.f = []float64{2,3}

    n.i = []int{2,3}
    n.f = []float64{4,5}

    u = UnnamedTypes(n)
}
```

fails with `cannot convert n (type NamedTypes) to type UnnamedTypes`

Comment: When you alias types, they become a new type. They are not equivalent, despite the temptation to think so.

Comment: yup I know, I now edited my question to ask, what's the easiest way to assign one to the other if all the field names are the same.

Comment: The struct types are different, so you can't convert it. You need to assign the fields individually.

Comment: Your "unnamed types" are not unnamed. You might want to read the spec.

Comment: @Volker yes they are, according to the spec: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types

Comment: @Adrian `UnnamedTypes` is a named type and thus not unnamed.

Comment: I believe they're referring to the types of the *fields*, since that is what is different between the two examples. Perhaps reread the question.

Answer (score 3):

Create a new struct value using the old ones.

```
u = UnnamedTypes{
    i: n.i,
    f: n.f,
}
```

A warning though, because these specific values are slices, the slices in the two different structs are the exact same slices. Modifying one will modify the other. The same will apply to any pointers as well (including maps and interfaces). If you want them to have their own copy, you must allocate a copy.